# json deserialization with a changeable class name

Tags: json, vb.net

i know how to deserialize java using JavaScriptSerializer but with this json string it is not working for some reason

This is the json string :

```
{"hell": {
   "id": 31930845,
   "name": "Hell",
   "profileIconId": 550,
   "revisionDate": 1440028482000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

and here is my class :

```
Public Class Summoner
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property profileIconId As Integer
    Public Property revisionDate As Long
    Public Property summonerLevel As Integer
End Class
```

My code

```
Dim j As New JavaScriptSerializer
 Dim o As Summoner = j.Deserialize(Of Summoner)(json)
```

i keep on getting empty values like 0 from id and empty string from name

Comment: Here's a cool free online utility that will take a JSON string and generate a .Net class definition based on it - http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class structure is a little incomplete. Instead try -

```
public class Summoner
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Summoner hell { get; set; }
}

var t = new StreamReader("jsonpath");
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(t.ReadToEnd());
```

[image]